# Symfony - Cannot configure Denormalizer

Tags: symfony

I'm looking for built-in Symfony denormalizer that will denormalize my array to an object.

I'm trying to get it by autowire in controller's action but it I got an error:

> Class Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface does not exist

Code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;

class MyController
{
    public function myAction(DenormalizerInterface $denormalizer)
    {
       dump($denormalizer);die;
    }

}
```

Is there any ready to use denormalizer in Symfony 5?

Comment: When I try to use `denormalize` method via `(new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()]))->denormalize(...);` I'm getting insane exception: `Attempted to load class "Serializer" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Serializer".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Serializer"?`

Comment: Use the question's Edit button (lower left corner) to update your question with new info instead of using comments.  bin/console debug:container DenormalizerInterface should reveal that there is indeed an alias for the denormalizer.  Which implies your original code will work assuming your MyController is properly tagged with controller.service_arguments.  I assume you chopped your posted code down?  Does MyController extend from AbstractController?  The error also indicates an autoload issue.  Run composer dump-autoload to see if that helps.